# Is there a way to import data from one Google sheet into another by the name of the sheet file?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for a dynamic way to link data from another google sheet.
In an ideal world, I would have kind of a search query that looks through all my existing google sheet names and opens the one with the matching name so I can access data from it.

This should be linked in a cell similar to an `IMPORTRANGE` function but in this case not with a link to the other sheet instead, I want to link it by a name.

I want to save the amount of work and maintenance that comes with finding all the worksheet links manually and copy pasting them into a formula. I want to automate the procedure of looking for the link every time a new document gets created and the need for creating an import range function with it. Instead, I want it to automatically find the dependent worksheet.

So an example could be I have a MASTER_SHEET.googlesheetsdoc that carries all data from January.googlsheetsdoc, February.googleshetsdoc...
As all data from different month is collected in different documents I have to get the link to every document manually to access the data in in.
If there would be a formula like `IMPORTRANGE`with a name attribute I could work like this in my MASTER_SHEET instead.

`IMPORTRANGE(SEARCHQUERY(January), A:1:C:10)`
`IMPORTRANGE(SEARCHQUERY(February), A:1:C10)`

And it would always find the necessary data. Without someone copy and paste the link to the document. So more modern and dynamic approach.

I haven't used AppScript for now.

Comment: Hello @BenjaminK, I have seen that the method provided below was not of help to you. What do you mean by "find the dependent worksheet"? Would you mind providing more details about what you want to achieve? Moreover, have you tried to make use of Apps Script? Cheers!

Comment: @ale13 I updated the question for you. Thanks for now!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a table of sheet names and urls
2. Now it is trivial to
       use the importrange function with a vlookup to your table.

[You can accomplish all of this with the DriveApp object.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive)

Comment: I guess for some that would be a working approach. But as this would be the same amount of work and maintanace as inserting the link into the import range function it wouldn't work for me. I want to automate the procedure of looking for the link every time a new document gets created and the need for creating an import range function with it. Instead, I want it to automatically find the dependent worksheet.

Comment: @BenjaminK Just recreate the table with the `DriveApp` object every time there is an edit or the sheet is opened? Of course you realize that there is always going to be duplicate name sheets so you will need to decide how you want to handle that.

Comment: sorry I'm not sure If I understand you? What do you mean by "object every time there is an edit or the sheet is opened"? Naming wise for sure I need to use unique names.

Comment: @BenjaminK you can do step 1 in the OnEdit function and that will accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no direct way** for this task to be achieved in the way you would like it to.

But, you can make use of **Apps Script**. Apps Script is a powerful development platform which can be used to build web apps and automate tasks. What makes it special is the fact that it is easy to use and to create applications that integrate with G Suite.

So you can use a simple script that would ask the user to input the name of the file and afterwards build the formula.

#### Snippet

```
function onOpen(e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
        .createMenu('Import Range Menu')
        .addItem('Import Range', 'importData')
        .addToUi();
}

function importData() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var response = ui.prompt('Please input the name of the spreadsheet', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    var name = response.getResponseText();
    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);
    if (files.hasNext() == false) 
        ui.alert("Please input a valid spreadsheet name!");
    else {
        var file = files.next();
        var url = file.getUrl();
        var formula = '=IMPORTRANGE(' + '"' + url + '"' + ',"A1:C10")';
        ss.getRange("RANGE_YOU_WANT_THE_FORMULA_IN").setFormula(formula);
    }
}
```

#### Explanation

The `onOpen(e)` function is a trigger and this means that each time the main sheet opens, a custom menu named `Import Range Menu` with the `Import Range` submenu will appear on your spreadsheet.

[image: import range menu]

By clicking the `Import Range` submenu, the `importData()` function will be executed. The `importData()` function will prompt the user with the below message.

[image: ui prompt]

You will be able to input the name of the file wanted and the input will be retrieved by using the `getResponseText()`. If no files are found with the wanted name, the script will return an alert message asking the user to input a valid file name. The url of the file will be gathered by using the `getUrl()` method and will be used in building the formula.

#### Note

In this case, when retrieving the **files** with the inputted name, only the first finding will be used as it is assumed that you don't have multiple files with the same name.

If you want to make this script more accurate, you can also put all the files you need in a particular folder and later retrieve them using the same method. When retrieving the file/s, you can also check for their `MIME TYPE` and make sure they are spreadsheets and not other file types. You will have to use unique names for these ones as well.

Moreover, the formula used in this script was just an `IMPORTRANGE` formula, but you can customize it however you like and choose the range in which you would like the formula to be set.

#### Reference

- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script);
- [Drive Service Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive);
- [DriveApp Class getFilesByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByName(String));
- [Apps Script Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers);
- [Ui Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui).